# downloaded Django-1.4.1 and unable to tar

Tags: django, gzip, tar

I am trying to download/install Django and the documentation on the Django website says to download Django-1.4.1.tar.gz file and then to issue these commands:

```
$ tar xzvf Django-1.4.1.tar.gz
$ cd Django-1.4.1
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

When I do `tar xzvf Django-1.4.1.tar.gz` I get:

```
$ tar xzvf Django-1.4.1.tar.gz
tar (child): Django-1.4.1.tar.gz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Are you using `tar xzvf Django-1.4.1.tar.gz tar` or `tar xzvf Django-1.4.1.tar.gz`? It's not clear to me. If it's the second one, your are telling `tar` to extract the file or directory named "tar" from the archive Django-1.4.1.tar.gz. If you want to extract the entire contents of Django-1.4.1.tar.gz, you shouldn't be specifying anything after the name of the archive.

Comment: 1.4 or 1.4.1 ? Please copy and paste in the exact command you're using, as this isn't the same as the original question

Comment: If you run the command `ls` do you see the Django-1.4.1.tar.gz file listed? Also, the file (Django-1.4.tar.gz) you just mentioned does not match what you typed above.

Comment: On most unix systems you should be able to just double-click the archive and it will be extracted automatically. Just in case that you feel more comfortable with a file browser instead of the command line.

Answer (score 5):

It seems like `Django-1.4.1.tar.gz` is not present in your current working directory. You can verify this by executing following command in terminal

```
$ ls -l Django-1.4.1.tar.gz
```

If file is present then you will see some details in command output otherwise you will need to switch to the directory in which you download `Django-1.4.1.tar.gz` in first place. For example - if you have downloaded `Django-1.4.1.tar.gz` in `$HOME/Downloads` then first switch to that directory before executing `tar`

```
$ cd ~/Downloads
```

Following commands should work if everything is correct -

```
$ tar xzvf Django-1.4.1.tar.gz
$ cd Django-1.4.1
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

### Alternative

Download `Django-1.4.1.tar.gz` from command line itself and then unpack it using `tar`. Try following commands -

```
$ cd /tmp/
$ wget http://www.djangoproject.com/m/releases/1.4/Django-1.4.1.tar.gz
$ tar xzvf Django-1.4.1.tar.gz
$ cd Django-1.4.1
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

Answer (score 2):

Strange as it may seem, the Django-1.4.1.tar.gz is not there. Either you mis-spelled, or there might be an error in the documentation (unlikely), maybe the name ends in .tgz instead of .tar.gz .

Or you are running those commands in a terminal with a different working directory from the one you downloaded the tar file in. Maybe, for example, the file is in /home/user/Downloads, but the terminal opens in /home/user. Check the file name and its location.

If you discover that the file is in /who/knows/what/dir/Django-1.4.1.tar.gz you can replace the first command with "tar xzvf /who/knows/what/dir/Django-1.4.1.tar.gz" and it should work.